# How to rotate a drawable but not the imageView itself?

Tags: android, drawable, android-animation

I'have an image view with a drawable inside. This drawable is a ring similar to the one present in progress dialog :

loading_ring :

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <size
        android:width="20dip"
        android:height="20dip"/>

    <gradient
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#4c737373"
        android:centerColor="#4c737373"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"/>
</shape>
```

In order to rotate this ring i have created a rotate animation like this :

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="359"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

but when i apply the animation on the imageView :

```
this.cameraView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.loadinganimation));
```

The all imageView is rotating. I would like to rotate only the ring (the src of the imageview) how can i achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two separated views and use a `FrameLayout` to contain them. This way you will be able to apply the animation to the ring and not to the rest of the widgets.

EDIT:

I guess you are placing the shape inside the `ImageView` with `android:src` and setting something else with `android:background`. If that is the case, instead of using an `ImageView` you can try:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ImageView with the background>
  <ImageView with JUST the shape>
</FrameLayout>
```

or

```
<FrameLayout android:background="blah">
  <ImageView with JUST the shape>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you detail a little bit your answer ? What do you mean by "Make two separated views" , two view for what ?

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. i was already using this "trick" , but i was hoping there is a more cleaner approach. Upvote anyway and waiting a little before accepting ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
// load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
       R.drawable.android);

int width = bitmapOrg.width();
int height = bitmapOrg.height();

// createa matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// rotate the Bitmap
matrix.postRotate(45);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                  width, height, matrix, true);

// make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
// to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

// set the Drawable on the ImageView
imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

For details check this out.

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Comment: This solution is good to a one time rotation thing. I'm not sure it gonna be usefull for an unlimited (in time) rotation.